# Publicar site no IIS dá erro no debug

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, iis, deploy

Tenho um problema um pouco estranho. Estou a desenvolver um site `MVC` no VS2013, tenho um site **IIS** configurado para o meu projeto.

Assim que faço publish do meu site para o **IIS**, a seguir, quando lanço o site em debug (no VS) recebo um erro (500) do **IIS** no **Visual Studio** (não consegue encontrar a .dll do `Web.Helpers`). Assim que apaguei tudo na pasta do site do **IIS** consigo correr em debug sem qualquer problema.

Alguém já passou por algo semelhante? Como posso resolver este conflito para puder ter uma versão compilada do site a correr no **IIS**, mas ao mesmo tempo puder fazer mudanças no projeto e testa-las em debug?

Comment: Seu código usa uma DLL que não existe no servidor. Localize a referência a Web.Helpers no projeto, abra as propriedades (selecione a referência e pressione F4) e marque a opção para sempre copiar ao publicar/fazer *deploy*. Assim você poderá depurar no servidor após a próxima publicação.